# Failed to design a search result page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap trying to learn, I need to divide the page into two sections, each sections shows a list of products and each products has its description. I wrote following code but does not work as expected.

Expected output would be similar to Google result page. Two panels at the center of the page. In my case, on each panel I would have a list of employees along with their details as following

**output of both panels**

```
    Name:                                 Logo of Company
    Surname:                 Employee ID
    Phone:
   -------------------------------------------------------------
    Name:                                 Logo of Company
    Surname:                 Employee ID
    Phone:
```

**BootStrap**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>List of Employees</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="background-color:lavender;">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:green;">
         <div class="row">Name:</div>
         <div class="row">Surname:</div>
         <div class="row">Phone:</div>
      </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">
         <div class="row">Name:</div>
         <div class="row">Surname:</div>
         <div class="row">Phone:</div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

With help of yuyokk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004929/failed-to-design-a-search-result-page/29005128#29005128) I could change the code to the following but still do not know how to remove the space between the panels.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>List of Employees</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div style="margin-bottom:2px;text-align:left;background-color:green;">
          <div>Name: Name result <img style="float:right;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/522909800191901697/FHCGSQg0.png" width="40px" height="40px"/></div>

          <div>Surname: Surname result <div style="float:right;">Employee Id:122</div></div>
          <div>Phone: phone result</div>

        </div>
         <div style="margin-bottom:1px; background-color:red;">
          <div>Name: Name result</div>
          <div>Surname: Surname result</div>
          <div>Phone: phone result</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div style="background-color:yellow;">
          <div>Name: Name result <img style="float:right" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/522909800191901697/FHCGSQg0.png" width="40px" height="40px"/></div>

          <div>Surname: Surname result <div style="float:right;">Employee Id:133</div></div>
          <div>Phone: phone result</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you use .row class in a wrong way.
You should have

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6"></div> <!-- all your col classes have to be inside .row Basically row is a holder for col classes. No need yo use it everywhere -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/HZPPeVEnDTDHSsACGjmI?p=preview

Comment: Alright thanks, how about employee id and logo of the company?

Comment: do you need something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/zfLaxwq1gNUhAVyJVd4Z?p=preview ?

Comment: no, both panels each employee record should have name, surname, phone, employee id and logo of company. So need to move employee id and logo of company to the left panel and have exactly the same results in the right panel as well. Also the panels should be at the centre of the page. Thats why I added <div class="col-md-2"></div>, also the panels should stick to each other, how to remove the space between them. Thanks

Comment: for centering you should use container class instead of container-fluid. http://plnkr.co/edit/zfLaxwq1gNUhAVyJVd4Z?p=preview the spacing is by default for bootstrap .col- classes so you have to write class to remove padding.

Comment: I see, quite confused with this.

Comment: It's all about practice. Just keep experimenting

Comment: I managed to change the code, the question is updated. would you help with the last part.

Comment: quick but not the best solution http://plnkr.co/edit/zfLaxwq1gNUhAVyJVd4Z?p=preview Better is to use some class, and then in css remove padding.